# How to print out register offsets in a Visual Studio trace point?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging, assembly, cpu-registers

I'm using a Visual Studio [trace point](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fhya4x5t.aspx) in a function I don't own (part of Windows' `user32.dll`), and I want to print out the function's parameters.

If I had the source code for the function I could use the following syntax.

> In Function( {arg1}, {arg2} ) called from $CALLER

However, I don't have debug information for `user32.dll` therefore I can't reference `arg1`. In the watch window I'm able to see the variables by offsetting from a register (`*(int*)(ESP+4)`), but I can't figure out how to do this in the print option of the trace point.

When I try the following:

> In Function( {*(int*)($ESP+4)}, {*(bool*)($ESP+8)} ) called from $CALLER

I get: **In Function( , ) called from OtherFunction**

Any ideas if this is possible?

Comment: Now that you've edited your question, I think it's not about tracepoint anymore, it's about how to debug the system's code.

Comment: @AssafLevy really? I didn't think I made any major edits, I want to check what system calls my code calls (I'm not looking for bugs in Win32)

Comment: @Motti. Please see also my latest edit. Maybe you should setup your access to the Microsoft symbol servers also and provide a local cache directory. I find it very usefull... It takes some time in the begining untill it fills the cache.

Comment: I had the feeling the system was trying to protect itself (e.g. you can't boot windows with /debug and play Windows Media with certain codecs. I also found Skype to hang the system in that mode :))

Comment: @ds27680 I am using MS's symbol server, did something I say give you the idea I as not? (otherwise I could not have placed the breakpoint in the first place).

Comment: @Motti - even without symbols you can place a breakpoint alas it could be that it takes a little bit of stepping through the assembler code until you get to the point where the function you are interested in gets called. Then you could take the address of the function and create the breakpoint at that address. The disadvantage is that it's more work and that you do not know if the address will be stable in time (i.e. the dll will always load at the same address and so on). Your sentence: "However I don't have debug information for user32.dll" made me believe you do not have the symbols.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not certain if this is possible in Visual Studio. At least the documented possibilities for tracepoints seem not to cover what you need.

One alternative solution would be to use WinDbg (includded in [Debugging Tools for 
Windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463009). With WinDbg you could for instance:

> bp kernel32!CreateFileW "du poi(@esp+4); gc"

This command:

1. Sets a breakpoint on the function you are interested in (**bp**).
2. On breakpoint hit executes the part in " ". This prints out the parameter you are interested in and continues debugging. I.e. for the CreateFile example:

**du** - prints out the unicode string at the address pointed to (**poi**) by (@esp+4)

**gc** - command resumes execution from a conditional breakpoint in the same fashion that was used to hit the breakpoint (stepping, tracing, or freely executing).

I hope this helps.

**EDIT:** Following Assaf Levy's now deleted reply (I wanted to vote it up because it helped with learning something/gave me the push to try it again in VS :-). Unfortunately he was faster with deleting than I was with voting up.

I managed to get tracing working for CreateFile (filename) in a similar way I did in WinDbg in Visual Studio (For reference I use 2010). What I did:

1. I chose "Go to disassembly" while in the debugger and went down up to the CreateFileW call. I took the name of the function from there (i.e. _CreateFileW@28).
2. I went in the breakpoints window, selected New -> Break at function... (Ctrl + B). Entered the name (_CreateFileW@28). I tried the WinDbg way also (kernel32!CreateFileW) but it does not work (not supported?)
3. Selected "When hit..." on the breakpoint and entered: "CreateFileW FileName: {*((const wchar_t**)(@esp+4))}", Continue Execution was selected.

With my test code now, something in the lines of:

CreateFileW FileName: 0x7efddc00 "c:\Temp\test.out"

is printed out for a CreateFile call.

So in principle it works/should work in VS also. It takes some fiddling but it works.

**EDIT2:** Also It might help/make things easier if you set up the usage of "Microsoft Symbol Servers". Please see: [Use a Symbol Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b8ttk8zy.aspx). It can be made to work also without symbol servers, but you have to adapt step 1 and use an address instead of the symbolic name when you create the breakpoint.

Comment: Thanks the `@` works (I tried with `$`). I see that @Assaf also used `$`, I'm not sure why it worked for him (it didn't for me).

Comment: I deemed it irrelevant in view of Motti's edition, but if it helped someone it's now *un*deleted :) And a great catch with `@`!

Answer (score 3):

Unless I'm missing something, this works for me:
`In foo: ({*(int*)($ESP+4)},{*(int*)($ESP+8)}) called from $CALLER`
Gives me exactly the two int's that I passed.

Comment: Here you go. One upvote from me as promissed. Thanks for making me wonder. Hey I tried that and it didn't work! Let me try this once more... Maybe I mispelled something...

Comment: Well, I'm using the `$` sign in my VS2005 for sure. I actually have little experience with trace points but your question intrigued me.

Comment: OK could be a difference between VS8 and VS10